# How to display utf-8 characters in hbase shell?

Tags: shell, hbase

when I use `get` command in hbase shell,like:

```
hbase(main)> get 't1','00003ab'
```

result is:

```
 PATHID:path0     timestamp=1463537742385, value={"pathSign":"\xE5\x8C\x97\xE5\xAE\x89\xE9\x97\xA8\xE8\xA1\x97"}  //hexadecimal
```

The utf-8 characters is displayed to **hexadecimal**.

Comment: what should it display?

Comment: @Whitefret Normal characters that you can recognize it. `\xE5\x8C\x97\xE5\xAE\x89\xE9\x97\xA8\xE8\xA1\x97` is bytes code.

Comment: Totally helps. .. i tried a hex to string converter and it gave nothing